# Playback duration of string harmonics in Sibelius

Tags: sibelius

I am currently notating some string harmonics in Sibelius (2020.9), and am using the "Harmonics playback" plugin to hear the natural harmonics at their actual pitch.

One example is of a natural harmonic "E" on the violin, played by bowing the A string and resting the finger at E. This creates the sound of the E note one octave above where the finger is resting.

I've notated this with a normal (type 0) notehead at A above middle C, and a diamond (type 2) notehead at E a 5th above. When I apply the plugin, the harmonic sounds at the correct pitch; however, it will not hold the pitch for the duration of the note value. No matter which note value I choose (minim, semibreve, etc.) it will only sound for a crotchet's duration.

Does anybody know of a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden note in another voice at the desired pitch/duration.

> To make the harmonic play back, make the printed pitch use a silent notehead, and add the sounding pitch of the harmonic using a hidden note in another voice

From *[Sibelius Reference Guide](http://resources.avid.com/SupportFiles/Sibelius/2019.4/Sibelius_Reference.pdf)* 2019.4, page 607, from Section 6.6 "Interpretation of Your Score", "Harmonics".